# How to return list of places? Geocoder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I use geocoder gem. When I write some place, for example New York and then save it. I get coordinates in my model. It works. 
But I won't to get list of places in my input (like google maps) 
when I write street or else address in field.

Comment: code would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the Google [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?hl=en) API.

A quick google search surfaced this [gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails)